# Reload app even after app crash in ios like android

Tags: ios, exception

In Android, there is a method

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
```

When crashed it could be called and make a function to land the app on the home page. Is there any similar methods in ios to make app open even after the crash.

Comment: You want the app to automatically restart after a crash? You can't do that in iOS.

Comment: there are many work around for that, first all of you can handle the application crashed using your own class

Comment: @Quicklearner learner As I am going to use instabug to send reports after the app crashed, Do you have idea ,if is there any methods available in instabug to be called?

Comment: @DineshKumar since you'll be using Instabug anyway, there's no need to do anything from your side. Instabug (and any other crash reporter) is going to automatically catch the crashes and report them on the next launch of the app. There's no way, however, to automatically relaunch the app after it has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar function in iOS [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409609-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler).

**UPD:**

Unfortunately, there is no way to reopen app after crash. Top-level error-handler only can log some additional information before the program terminates.

From docs:

> Sets the top-level error-handling function where you can perform last-minute logging before the program terminates.

Comment: If you're not sure if it works (it doesn't), it probably shouldn't be an answer.